# time, space complexity and O notation problem

Tags: algorithm, big-o

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Plain English explanation of Big O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o)

I can't find any sufficient help for learn or understand about O-notation, 
and how learn about time or space complexity.
So please suggest me , where can I start this.
Its really need to me, for now these time.So please give me solution quick.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This is such an exact duplicate (of several dozen questions on this site); why has no one voted to close this?!

Comment: sorry sir I had also try to find this type of question but I am not satisfied with any question, so I asked, I am also don't want to ask repetitive question. I know every one has valuable time. Sorry for this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best explanation of Big O I've ever seen:

[What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258)

Comment: thank you very much
this link help me so much
and how to contact with you

Answer (score 6):

[image: Algorithms]

Comment: I posted the same thing but without the nice pic. I will upvote for great pic.
What a great book.

Comment: thanks but I v got this just 2 hours ago. I m not sure to go with this because its huge, and I want to go with basic.I m not sure If you have gone this through then what should I do, go with this or at first take help of any basic note or book. If I should do with basic then which?

Comment: hey Daniel if now online now can u response?

Comment: Go through it.  Don't be daunted by the size, it is big because it is thorough, not because it is difficult.  Also see the associated lectures http://www.catonmat.net/blog/mit-introduction-to-algorithms-part-one  (this is the link I have bookmarked.  The lectures are at MIT, but the blogs commentary is also very good)

Comment: thanks
how to contact with you
I want more help from you, If you wish

Answer (score 0):

Uh, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)? Although Big O notation (and algorithm analysis in general) is a pretty broad and substantial topic, so I doubt you're going to find a "quick solution" to learning it.

Answer (score 0):

[Introduction to Algorithms](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844)

Also 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Also, there are some great lectures out there on youtube and itunesU

Answer (score 0):

"[Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201558025)" would be another book recommendation I'd toss out there.  Big O isn't that difficult but it can take a while to get the hang of what it is trying to convey.